# check str.contains in pandas using string from series

Tags: python, string, pandas

Why doesn't this work for string methods using pandas?

```
df['col1'].str.contains(df['col2'])
```

Keep getting:  'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

Update:  To clarify - I would to compare these columns row-by-row, and for the partial string to match exactly in order.  For example, for column 1 and column 2 below, I would want the output of the above to be as in output:

```
col-1    col-2    output
'cat'    'at'     True
'aunt'   'at'     False
'dog'    'dg'     False
'edge'   'dg'     True
```

Comment: `contains` takes a pattern, I think you want `.isin` so `df['col1'].isin(df['col2'])`

Comment: I think you need `df['col1'].isin(df['col2'].values)`, right?

Comment: So it doesn't matter that I only want to match part of the string?  'mn' isin 'mnxn' will be true?

Comment: No, `isin` does a complete match, for partial matches you have to use `contains`, I'll update my answer to demonstrate

Comment: Thanks @EdChum.  I need to clarify - I want to match the value in one column against the value in another, row by row.  So in your [77] below, row index 4 should be False... because there is no 'q' in 'xa'.  Also it must be order specific. If column one says 'ant', and column two says 'at',  the answer would be 'false'.  But if column one says 'cat' it should be 'true'.

Comment: so you want to do this row-wise, I'll update my answer but you should be very clear about what you want with input desired output and code

Comment: good point.  i was pretty vague - i will update my question.  I appreciate the help.  I've been trying this for months and just keep giving up saying I'll "come back to it later".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a simple function and just use a test for whether one value in one column is in another:

```
In [37]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['mn','mxn','ca','sd','xa','ac'], 'col2':['m','n','x','n','q','y']})
def func(x):
    return x.col2 in list(x.col1)
df.apply(func, axis=1)
Out[37]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

For your use case the following should do what you want:

```
return x.col2 in x.col1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lambda function for doing any operations in dataframe rowwise.

For your question:

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col-1':['cat','aunt','dog','edge'], 'col-2':['at','at','dg','dg']})

>> df
 col-1 col-2
0   cat    at
1  aunt    at
2   dog    dg
3  edge    dg

>> df['output'] = df.apply(lambda row : row['col-2'] in row['col-1'], axis=1)

>> df
  col-1 col-2  output
0   cat    at    True
1  aunt    at   False
2   dog    dg   False
3  edge    dg    True
```

Here the lambda function will perform a rowwise string comparison for col-1 and col-2, and stores the result in 'output' column.

Similarly the same concept can be used to perform mathematical operations on the dataframe as well.